# medusa js custom payment plugin can not test locally

Tags: plugins, stripe-payments, payment-method, medusajs, medusa

I am trying to develop a custom plugin for adding custom payment provider. I follow the instructions from the docs https://docs.medusajs.com/development/plugins/publish but when I try to test plugin in local machine using npm link it dose not work and I can not test my plugin. how can I fix it. please help me

I also test, medusa-payment-stripe from medusa plugin market https://medusajs.com/plugins/medusa-payment-stripe/ using npm install medusa-payment-stripe, it work properly but when I copy the stripe plugin code from the medusa core to check is it work  locally then I found  it does not work locally.

I also , added provider_id manually in database at payment_provider table but it give me following error

`{ "type": "not_found", "message": "Could not find a payment provider with id: stripe" }`

---

Answer (score 0):

when you run your backend you should preserve symlinks for your backend to start with the linked pluging you can acheave that by this command :

```bash
npm run dev --  -- --preserve-symlinks
```

or you can add it to your `package.json` scripts:

```
"dev:link": "cross-env npm run dev --  -- --preserve-symlinks"
```

and run it with :

```
yarn dev:link
```

Note: dont forget to add your plugin to your `medusa-config.js`